# Issue found : missing independent security review on your data safety form

Tags: android, google-play

We found an issue in the following area(s):

Policy Declaration—Data Safety Section

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "App content" menu item in the Google Play console menu has a "Data Safety" section that contains a page "Data collection and security" where there is a question:

"Is your app currently certified by an authorized lab, according to the Mobile Application Security Assessment (MASA) framework?"

It is explained like this:

> Performing regular security testing can help developers identify key
> vulnerabilities in their apps. Google Play will allow developers who
> have completed independent validation to showcase this on their Data
> safety section. This helps users feel more confident about an app's
> commitment to security and privacy.

You should answer "No" to this question unless you actually have contracted an authorized lab and received an independent validation.

[image: Screenshot from Google Play console]

Comment: I received the issue email but cannot find where to disable the independent security review

Comment: Same thing here, received email, I don't remember what I did first time with external review, but now I cannot find any place to disable it in the Data Safety form (my app doesn't collect data). Anyone can help? Coming from Apple, I find the Google Play Console a total absolute nightmare.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be accurate anymore. There is no such section available in the Policy - Data Safety - Data collection and security section at the moment.

Comment: @Sarah but you still got your app rejected because of this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a Google mistake.

In my case, I contacted the Google Customer Center and requested to cancel the matter.

I had two apps, both had the same situation as above. Fortunately, one has been resolved, but the rest seem to remain.

I hope Google will fix this soon. I was worried for a few days because of the warning email,

but it would be better for everyone to contact the customer center below. Google should make this point.

-Google Support-

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/?hl=ko#topic=3450769